# Trazer informação descritiva de uma sequencia em PHP

Tags: php, html, oracle

Tenho um formulário, um dos campos é um dropdown que faz consulta e traz os resultados conforme abaixo:

```
<select name="convenio" id="convenio" class="input" style="width:260px">
                                    <option value="selecione"><--- Selecione uma opção ---> </option>
                                    <? while (($exibe = oci_fetch_array($parsed_conv, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
                                                $CD_CONVENIO    = $exibe ['CD_CONVENIO'];   
                                                $DS_CONVENIO    = $exibe ['DS_CONVENIO'];
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?=$CD_CONVENIO?>"><?=$DS_CONVENIO?></option>
                                    <? } ?>
</select>
```

Tenho os resultados esperados no formulário.

Depois de preenchido, em um method post, envio os dados do formulário para outra pagina.

Nessa outra página, recebo a informação do campo a cima conforme abaixo:

```
$NM_CONVENIO       = $_POST['convenio'];
```

Essa variável `$NM_CONVENIO` está recebendo os dados da coluna `CD_CONVENIO`, não quero isso, quero que ela receba a descrição dessa sequencia, ou seja, outra coluna, a `DS_CONVENIO` apresentada no formulário. Como eu posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que precise apenas alterar esta linha de codigo, colocando $DS_CONVENIO no value:

```
<option value="<?=$DS_CONVENIO?>"><?=$DS_CONVENIO?></option>
```